# Determine which device resumed PC from suspend

Tags: suspend, power-management

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 as a HTPC and have configuring the PC to resume from suspend in order to record scheduled live TV programs. This part works fine.

What I want to do now is determine what caused the PC to resume from the suspend state.

How can I tell if resume from suspend was caused by the real-time clock (rtc) using `rtcwake`, the power button or the USB keyboard?

I've checked the `pm-powersave` and `pm-suspend` logs but nothing is jumping out at me.

The reason I need this is that if the rtc caused the resume then after recording I can suspend the PC again, otherwise I can leave it powered on.

I'd be thankful for any tips you can provide.